# Async function returns undefined even though values are returned

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following two functions one calling the other but the record variable is undefined followed by errors. I can't figure out why the script doesn't wait. It seems to just proceed with the undefined variable.

```js
async function searchRecord(recordID) {
    client.search({
        index: 'records',
        type: 'record',
        body: {
            query: { match: { _id: recordID } }
        }
    }).then(result => {
        return result
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        return []
    })
}

function test(jsonRecord) {
    const userID = jsonRecord.users[0]
    searchRecord(jsonRecord.objectID).then(record => {
        if (record.length === 0) {
            record = jsonRecord
        }
    })
}
```

The error that I get is:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: searchRecord forgot to `return` anything.

Comment: @tmhao2005 `async` functions always return a promise. In this case since there's no return statement, the function will return a promise that resolves immediately with `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating `searchRecord` to `return`:

```
async function searchRecord(recordID) {
  return client
    .search({
      index: "records",
      type: "record",
      body: {
        query: {
          match: { _id: recordID },
        },
      },
    })
    .then((result) => {
      return result;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return [];
    });
}
```

Comment: Most solutions seemed to work but this was by far the easiest to implement. Strange that the top return is needed here to make this work but I guess the .then and .catch all return the values to the client .

Answer (score 2):

This is asynchronous, try using `await`.

```js
async function searchRecord(recordID) {
  try {
    const result = await client.search({
      index: 'records',
      type: 'record',
      body: {
        query: {
          match: { _id: recordID }
        }
      }
    });
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `client.search()` returns a promise. You could choose to return that promise as is from `searchRecord()`. And then, handle the `catch` in your `test()` function.

Alternatively you could also handle the error inside `searchRecord()` as well by implementing a try catch block. But the key in this case is to wait for `client.search()` to finish before returning from `searchRecord()`.

```js
function searchRecord(recordID) {
    return client.search({
        index: 'records',
        type: 'record',
        body: {
            query: { match: { _id: recordID } }
        }
    });
}

function test(jsonRecord) {
    const userID = jsonRecord.users[0]
    searchRecord(jsonRecord.objectID).then(record => {
        if (record.length === 0) {
            record = jsonRecord
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        return []
    })
}
```

> The error that I get is: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The reason for this is that `searchRecord()` returns promise that immediately resolves to `undefined`. There is no return statement in the function `searchRecord()`.

Answer (score -1):

why you not using `Promise`? it's ok if you want to use `async-await` like answers above but using `Promise` its became very easy

```js
function searchRecord (recordID) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    client.search({
      index: 'records',
      type: 'record',
      body: {
        query: {
          match: { _id: recordID }
        }
      }
    }).then(
      result => resolve(result)
    ).catch(
      error => {console.log(error);reject());
  });
}


function test (jsonRecord) {
    const userID = jsonRecord.users[0]
    searchRecord(jsonRecord.objectID)
      .then(
        record => {
          if (record.length === 0) {
            record = jsonRecord
          }
        }
      )
  }
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743).